# Next-Auth with FaunaDB Dev Get Session Error

Tags: next.js, faunadb, next-auth

I've set up Next-Auth on my NextJS project to use FaunaDB. I've managed to get it working on my production environment, however, it seems to not be working on my development environment, which is using the Fauna Dev docker container rather than the cloud-based database.

Whenever I run the dev server, I get the following error log;

```
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#fauna__get_session_error [NotFound: instance not found] {
  description: 'Set not found.',
  requestResult: RequestResult {
    method: 'POST',
    path: '',
    query: null,
    requestRaw: '{"get":{"match":{"index":"session_by_token"},"terms":"86b962d600c3f53d41d5140de6daed654a473e670a99943d7fb301a4fc86357e"}}',
    requestContent: Expr { raw: [Object] },
    responseRaw: '{"errors":[{"position":[],"code":"instance not found","description":"Set not found."}]}',
    responseContent: { errors: [Array] },
    statusCode: 404,
    responseHeaders: [Object: null prototype] {
      ':status': 404,
      'x-txn-time': '1630008523944000',
      'x-compute-ops': '1',
      'x-read-ops': '0',
      'x-byte-read-ops': '0',
      'x-byte-write-ops': '0',
      'x-write-ops': '0',
      'x-query-time': '703',
      'x-query-bytes-in': '121',
      'x-query-bytes-out': '87',
      'x-storage-bytes-read': '0',
      'x-storage-bytes-write': '0',
      'x-txn-retries': '0',
      'x-faunadb-build': '21.08.00-4d315fa',
      'content-length': '87',
      'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
    startTime: 1630008521471,
    endTime: 1630008522280
  }
}
```

I've followed the guide to set this up and continue to get the same error. I've removed and recreated the fauna docker container several times, still the same error. I also have some data that I can access in the local Fauna Dev database, so that seems to be set up fine. Also if I change my `.env.local` environment variables to the ones I use on production, it all works fine, but of course is then using the cloud database.

Here's a comparison of my production and local variables, with private keys removed;

```
# .env.local
GOOGLE_ID=<removed>
GOOGLE_SECRET=<removed>
NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUNA_ADMIN_KEY=<removed>
NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUNA_DOMAIN=localhost
NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUNA_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:8084/graphql
NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUNA_PORT=8443
NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUNA_SCHEME=http
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000

# production env
GOOGLE_ID=<removed, identical to local>
GOOGLE_SECRET=<removed, identical to local>
NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUNA_ADMIN_KEY=<removed, different to local>
NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUNA_DOMAIN=db.eu.fauna.com
NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUNA_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://graphql.eu.fauna.com/graphql
NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUNA_SCHEME=https
NEXTAUTH_URL=https://dnd-compendium-five.vercel.app
```

And for good measure, here's my `[...nextauth].ts` file;

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Providers from "next-auth/providers";
import * as Fauna from "faunadb";
import { FaunaAdapter } from "@next-auth/fauna-adapter";

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";


const client = new Fauna.Client({
  secret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUNA_ADMIN_KEY,
  scheme: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUNA_SCHEME === "https" ? "https" : "http",
  domain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUNA_DOMAIN,
  ...(isProduction ? {} : { port: +process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUNA_PORT }),
});

export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    Providers.Google({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  adapter: FaunaAdapter({ faunaClient: client }),
});
```

### Update

Here's several documents from the production Fauna database, with personal info removed;

```
# accounts collection document
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("accounts"), "307944413618766018"),
  "ts": 1629937528150000,
  "data": {
    "userId": "307944413481402562",
    "providerId": "google",
    "providerType": "oauth",
    "providerAccountId": "110736403335097897627",
    "accessToken": "ya29.a0ARrdaM_n4D6gDvzs8Mxs851r70Xs5v5HROSdcDM0HJoMP1XFhAPhFbmh46e4bfHzTbVYOhoc2W7N_0IHpV3yEW5a__Nzy8NrxWU3ns-KlxIm_oTXRVW0RyitT26uXtTq-45k6OTjakjHsinYpnof4qdXcICg",
    "createdAt": Time("2021-08-26T00:25:28.101705Z"),
    "updatedAt": Time("2021-08-26T00:25:28.101705Z")
  }
}

# sessions collection document
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("sessions"), "308011284890124486"),
  "ts": 1630001301580000,
  "data": {
    "userId": "307946306265940166",
    "expires": Time("2021-09-25T18:08:21.521Z"),
    "sessionToken": "997b45bb432cfbc05901e9a92ae9d1ac36637246277ac05ad915fb00b8fc9130",
    "accessToken": "9dbec0113a46bc6a0768e1a5b7baafac65a1fb0a29568bc11562cd58ad97d5b9",
    "createdAt": Time("2021-08-26T18:08:21.517447Z"),
    "updatedAt": Time("2021-08-26T18:08:21.517447Z")
  }
}

# users collection document
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("users"), "307946306265940166"),
  "ts": 1629939333135000,
  "data": {
    "name": <string removed>,
    "email": <string removed>,
    "image": <url string removed>,
    "createdAt": Time("2021-08-26T00:55:33.075553Z"),
    "updatedAt": Time("2021-08-26T00:55:33.075553Z")
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a query/data problem, and not an environment problem. Can you show us the query that results in the `instance not found` error, and the definition of any indexes involved? Plus one sample document that has PII/sensitive data obscured?

Comment: @eskwayrd I'm not sure exactly what query is being run, as it's run automatically in the background by next-auth. The indexes that have been set up are identical to what's on the guide page - https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/fauna#schema

I've updated the question with some documents from the production site.

Hopefully that's what you need, but if I've misunderstood do let me know. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: One thing that you might try is removing the `session_by_token` index, and then recreating it. If that makes a difference, that would be useful information for our engineering team.

Comment: @eskwayrd Didn't work, unfortunately. I removed the index and get the error description `"Ref refers to undefined index 'session_by_token'"`. Then I added it back in and got the same `'Set not found.'` error description I started with.

Comment: Do you have `fauna-shell` configured to connect to your Fauna Dev image? If so, can you show me the output for `Paginate(Match(Index("session_by_token"), "<a valid token id>"))`?

Comment: Actually, SO isn't for interactive problem solving. Can you ask your question again on forums.fauna.com? Once we determine the problem, we can complete your question here.

Comment: @eskwayrd Thanks for this, I've posted this on the forums at https://forums.fauna.com/t/next-auth-with-faunadb-dev-get-session-error/2425 along with the requested output.

Answer (score 1):

Which verisons of next-auth and the adapter are you using? They recently released a v4 beta and matching adapter beta's. Maybe you'll have more luck with those newer releases